# `patch:instead` removes an element with no attributes

Tags: configuration

I want to patch the configuration for `sharedSessionState` to use MSSQL instead of memory. The default configuration from `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config` renders as such:

**Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config**

```xml
<sharedSessionState defaultProvider="InProc">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="InProc" type="System.Web.SessionState.InProcSessionStateStore"/>
  </providers>
  <manager type="Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.SharedSessionState.SharedSessionStateManager, Sitecore.Analytics">
    <param desc="configuration" ref="tracking/sharedSessionState/config"/>
  </manager>
  <config type="Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.SharedSessionState.SharedSessionStateConfig, Sitecore.Analytics">
    <param desc="maxLockAge">5000</param>
    <param desc="timeoutBetweenLockAttempts">10</param>
  </config>
</sharedSessionState>
```

The goal is to change the `defaultProvider` attribute and to replace the `InProc` provider. I attempt to do this with the following patch file:

**z.Patch.config**

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <tracking>
      <sharedSessionState defaultProvider="InProc">
        <patch:attribute name="defaultProvider" value="mssql" />
        <providers patch:instead="providers">
          <clear />
          <add name="mssql" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql.SqlSessionStateProvider,Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql" connectionStringName="sharedsession" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" sessionType="shared"/>
        </providers>
      </sharedSessionState>
    </tracking>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

This patch results in the `sharedSessionState` correctly changing its `defaultProvider`, *but the `providers` element is completely missing*. At first I thought the patching engine couldn't find the right place to add the element, given that I changed its parent in the same configuration, but fiddling around I discovered that the following patch **does** include the `providers` element correctly:

**z.ModifiedPatch.config**

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <tracking>
      <sharedSessionState defaultProvider="InProc">
        <patch:attribute name="defaultProvider" value="mssql" />
        <providers customAttribute="whatever" patch:instead="providers">
          <clear />
          <add name="mssql" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql.SqlSessionStateProvider,Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql" connectionStringName="sharedsession" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" sessionType="shared"/>
        </providers>
      </sharedSessionState>
    </tracking>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

The only change introduced in this modified patch is the addition of `customAttribute="whatever"` to the `providers` element.

Why is it seemingly not possible replace an element with an attribute-less element? Is there a better work-around in general than to add a bogus attribute?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Explanation

This is not an expected behavior. This is a defect in the Sitecore XML patching engine.

In the method `Sitecore.Xml.Patch.XmlPatchHelper.InsertChild()`, there's the following code:

```cs
case 'i': // this corresponds to patch:instead
  parent.InsertBefore(child, xmlNode);
  parent.RemoveChild(xmlNode);
```

So in your case, the new `<providers>` element is first inserted before the existing `<providers>` element, and then the old element is removed.

The tricky thing is the implementation of the method `XmlNode.InsertBefore(newChild, refChild)`, which is a native XML method in .NET. This method has the following check:

```cs
if (newChild == refChild)
{
  return newChild;
}
```

So if the inserted node is the same in-memory object as the original node, nothing is going to happen. The new node will not be inserted, which means that the Sitecore code at `parent.RemoveChild(xmlNode)` is going to remove the `<providers>` node altogether.

I debugged through the Sitecore decompiled code and found that if both the original node and the new node have exactly the same data attributes (or no attributes at all), then `object.ReferenceEquals(child, xmlNode)` returns `true`. If the attributes differ, then it returns `false`, which means they are different objects and the replacement will succeed.

There's a defect somewhere in `XmlPatchHelper` that reuses the existing XML node object instead of creating a new one, which results in nothing being inserted, which in turn means the node being patched will be completely removed. This will only happen when using `patch:instead`.

I have registered this as a bug with Sitecore Support. If you want to track the status of the bug, use the reference number **94066**.

## Workarounds

It seems that currently you have the following options to work around this defect:

- Don't delete the existing providers—they won't be used anyway.
- First delete the whole node using `<patch:delete />` and then add it from scratch.
- Add a bogus attribute to the patch node so that it differs from the original node.

Hopefully, this will be fixed by Sitecore at some point.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to worry about removing the existing providers, instead just add another one and change the default provider to the new one:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <tracking>
      <sharedSessionState set:defaultProvider="mssql">
        <providers>
          <add name="mssql" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql.SqlSessionStateProvider,Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql" connectionStringName="sharedsession" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" sessionType="shared"/>
        </providers>
      </sharedSessionState>
    </tracking>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Note the above is using `set` to change the default provider value, it reads a little cleaner than the `patch:attribute` syntax but both do the same thing. You can read more about it in the [Include File Patching Facilities document](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/60/include_file_patching_facilities_sc6orlater-a4.pdf).

The merged config will then look like this, all other elements will remain unchanged and Sitecore will use whatever provider is defined as the default:

```xml
<tracking>
  <sharedSessionState defaultProvider="mssql">
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="InProc" type="System.Web.SessionState.InProcSessionStateStore"/>
      <add name="mssql" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql.SqlSessionStateProvider,Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql" connectionStringName="sharedsession" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" sessionType="shared"/>
    </providers>
    ...
  </sharedSessionState>
</tracking>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this specific example you are right - I don't need to remove the existing provider - but for other configurations it could have an impact. The answer doesn't address *why* the first configuration patch doesn't work.

Comment: "but for other configurations ***it*** could have an impact" -- I don't understand this comment. What's the *it* here?  In this scenario, you're trying to add a child element to a parent element and change an attribute. Pretty simple use case.  Is there another use case that you can provide that demonstrates the exact issue? I'm sincerely asking, cause I find @jammykams answer to fully answer this specific question.

Comment: It's quite rare to require an entire node to be deleted, generally you are supplementing Sitecore configuration. If you do then to delete, then @RichardSeal's answer to `patch:delete` first is generally the way to achieve this. This seems to be a limitation of the patching system.

Comment: Also note the best practice from the document I linked to: `Always Add New Provider Rather than Modify the Type of the Default`

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because of the way you are trying to patch the providers section. If you want to delete the `InProc` provider and just add your `mssql` one you can do it like this:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <tracking>
      <sharedSessionState defaultProvider="InProc">
        <patch:attribute name="defaultProvider" value="mssql" />
        <providers>
          <add name="InProc" type="System.Web.SessionState.InProcSessionStateStore">
            <patch:delete />
          </add>
          <add name="mssql" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql.SqlSessionStateProvider,Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql" connectionStringName="sharedsession" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" sessionType="shared"/>
        </providers>
      </sharedSessionState>
    </tracking>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Notice that we are using `patch:delete` to remove the `InProc` provider, then just adding the `mssql` node into the list will add it to the merged config.

**EDIT: Added a second option based on OP's comments**

Another option would be to remove the `providers` element completely using `patch:delete` and then add it back in. I have used this many times with the `<sites>` list in the `publish:end` events. The config would look like this:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <tracking>
      <sharedSessionState defaultProvider="InProc">
        <patch:attribute name="defaultProvider" value="mssql" />
        <providers>
            <patch:delete />
        </providers>
        <providers>
          <add name="mssql" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql.SqlSessionStateProvider,Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql" connectionStringName="sharedsession" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" sessionType="shared"/>
        </providers>
      </sharedSessionState>
    </tracking>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

As for which option you use will depend on how fine grained you want to be when removing child elements. If you want all gone and replaced with your updates, use option 2, if you want to only delete a few, option 1 is the best.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that `sharedSessionState` has more children elements than the one I want to modify, so if I were to delete and add, I would have to copy all the configuration from the original patch file into my own, which is worse than a rogue attribute in my opinion.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind deleting them tho. As long as you patch the `defaultProvider` with the one you want to use, Sitecore will use that one. Having the others in the config wont affect that.

Comment: That is correct, but it might not be true for other similar configurations.

Comment: I have updated to add a second option on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks, the second option is definitely a better option in my opinion. Do you know *why* it doesn't work? Is it documented behavior or is it merely a bug?